# Send Json to APNS using Push-Sharp library

Tags: c#, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I need to send json to IOS device like this:

```
    {"aps":{"content-available":1}}
```

Should I use  AppleNotification  or  AppleNotificationPayLoad class? please give sample code.Here is example how I create notification now:

```
        AppleNotification notification = NotificationFactory.Apple()
                                                      .ForDeviceToken(token)
                                                      .WithAlert(message)
                                                      .WithSound("default")
                                                      .WithBadge(7);
```

Answer (score 4):

As Eran mentioned, with PushSharp you can only send custom payload parameters outside of aps. So if you wanted to send something like this:

```
{"aps":{ whatever data... },"content-available":1}
```

You can do so like this:

```
// Add these to your references
using System.IO;
using PushSharp;
using PushSharp.Apple;
using PushSharp.Core;

//Create our push services broker
var push = new PushBroker();

//Registering the Apple Service and sending an iOS Notification
var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(string.Format(@"applePushCert.p12"));
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "password"));
push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
        .ForDeviceToken("your device token")
        .WithAlert("Hello World!")
        .WithBadge(7)
        .WithSound("sound.caf")
        .WithCustomItem("content-available", 1));
```

Comment: To pickup this custom item inside iOS and didReceiveRemoteNotification method.  Use this:  
    NSString *contentId = [userInfo objectForKey:@"content-available"];

Answer (score 2):

The JSON you are trying to send is invalid. You can't put custom properties in the `aps` dictionary.
If you want to send custom data, you should send it outside the `aps` dictionary, like this :

`{"aps":{},"content-available":1}`

You should look for methods in the PushSharp library that allow you to add custom data to the payload.

> Providers can specify custom payload values outside the Apple-reserved
>   aps namespace. Custom values must use the JSON structured and
>   primitive types: dictionary (object), array, string, number, and
>   Boolean.

EDIT :

You can use the `AddCustom(string key, params object[] values)` method of `AppleNotificationPayload`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old Thread, but I just searched for it in 2015 and couldn't find a solution on stack overflow. I believe the question now deserves an answer, as to use the

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void(^(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

method, you must include "content-available" **INSIDE** of the aps. [(see this excellent article for details)](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html)

I found that pushsharp accomodates for this by enabling you to tack `notification.WithContentAvailable(1)` on the end of your notification like so:

```
 var notification = new AppleNotification(deviceID1, payload1);
 notification.WithContentAvailable(1);//enable background fetch
```